# :radio selector with multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have this HTML environment in which I want to set as `.prop('checked', false)` two classes of radio button `class=IIlvl` and `class=IIIlvl` with one click. Since the same class is given also to the relative inputs, I was wondering if there's a clean method to do it with one line of code.

For example, this `$('.IIlvl, .IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);` works but I think it's not really clean since it sends the `.prop()` also to the inputs with same class (even if no error is displayed, so maybe it's just a personal paranoia).

I think the proper solution is something like this `$('input:radio[class=IIlvl], input:radio[class=IIIlvl]').prop('checked', false);`, but this doesn't work and I don't want to split it in two lines of code dividing the two classes.

Has anyone any suggestion?

```
<div id="aNP_SubCatSelectDiv">
    <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioSelect" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
    <select class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatSelect" name="aNP_SubCatSelect">
        <option value="null">- Sub category -</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="aNP_SubCatInputDiv">
    <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioInput" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
    <input type="text" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatInput" placeholder="New sub category">
</div>

<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect">
    <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
        <select class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
            <option value="null">- Family code -</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput">
    <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeInput">
        <input type="text" class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeInput" placeholder="New family code">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('input.IIlvl, input.IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);` specify they're inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple selector

```
$(':radio.IIlvl, :radio.IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);
```

Or, You can also experiment using `.filter()`

```
$('.IIlvl, .IIIlvl').filter(':radio').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$('.IIlvl, .IIIlvl').filter(':radio').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aNP_SubCatSelectDiv">
  <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioSelect" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
  <select class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatSelect" name="aNP_SubCatSelect">
    <option value="null">- Sub category -</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="aNP_SubCatInputDiv">
  <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioInput" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
  <input type="text" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatInput" placeholder="New sub category">
</div>

<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect">
  <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
  <select class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
    <option value="null">- Family code -</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput">
  <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeInput">
  <input type="text" class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeInput" placeholder="New family code">
</div>
```

Note: `$('input')` will also select `checkboxes` so its better to use `:radio`

Comment: This is what I also wrote, but since I didn't find this solution anywhere else but in my mind I thought it was syntactically incorrect! Is it better `:radio.IIlvl` or `.IIlvl:radio`? Or is it the same? Nice also the `filter()` solution

Comment: @brigo, both `:radio.IIlvl`/`.IIlvl:radio` are correct. There may be minor performance difference but you can use either of them

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to specify the element type:

```
$('input.IIlvl, input.IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);
```

As mention by @Satpal - this will target ALL inputs with these classes - to be more specific, just target radio inputs with:

```
$(':radio.IIlvl, :radio.IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: This is pretty the same of `$('.IIlvl, .IIIlvl').prop('checked', false);` I guess, since for each class there're two inputs with the same class: a radio and a text input

Comment: `$('.IIlvl, .IIIlvl')` will target everything with those classes, `$('input.IIlvl, input.IIIlvl')` will only target input elements

Comment: `$('input')` will also select `checkboxes` so its better to use `:radio`

Comment: Had there been multiple input types I would have done that yeah...just using info supplied, `input` seemed cleanest to me @Satpal

Answer (score 1):

You could add input type to your selctor like :

```
$('.IIlvl:radio, .IIIlvl:radio').prop('checked', false);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.IIlvl:radio, .IIIlvl:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aNP_SubCatSelectDiv">
  <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioSelect" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
  <select class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatSelect" name="aNP_SubCatSelect">
    <option value="null">- Sub category -</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="aNP_SubCatInputDiv">
  <input type="radio" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatRadioInput" name="aNP_SubCatRadio">
  <input type="text" class="IIlvl" id="aNP_SubCatInput" placeholder="New sub category">
</div>

<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect">
  <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
  <select class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeSelect" name="aNP_FamCodeSelect">
    <option value="null">- Family code -</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="aNP_FamCodeInputDiv" data-radio-id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput">
  <input type="radio" class="IIIlvl aNP_FamCodeRadio" id="aNP_FamCodeRadioInput" name="aNP_FamCodeRadio" data-input-id="aNP_FamCodeInput">
  <input type="text" class="IIIlvl" id="aNP_FamCodeInput" placeholder="New family code">
</div>
```